# Re-synchronize Linux to NTP server

Tags: linux, sms, sms-gateway, ntp

We're planning to re-synchronize 2 of our machines that's having a 19ms delay from the NTP server (this involves SMS transaction). Those servers are having discrepancy with analytics results and we're suspecting it's one of the cause.

So my question is, is it service affecting to re-sync the server to the NTP server? Thanks in advance! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If NTP is not already installed, use the following command to install:

```
// Ubuntu or other Debian-based system
sudo apt-get install ntp
// CentOS, Fedora or other RedHat-based system
yum install ntp
```

Then, config the settings:

```
vi /etc/ntp.conf
```

Find the server lines, and edit the server addresses to fit your needs:

```
server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
```

Restart the service to apply changes:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd restart
```

---

Use the following commands to sync the time with NTP server in Linux just once:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd stop
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Raptor but my real question is, is it service affecting especially when the servers and other networking equipment are in production or live traffic.

Comment: nope. this service has a very low consumption of system resources & finish quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it service affecting especially when the servers and other networking equipment are in production or live traffic

No.  But I'd re-examine my NTP setup to see why the clocks drifted.  By chance, are these virtual machines?  If so, differing types of virtual machines can be slaved to the physical server clock, or can run NTP themselves.

But it's hard to see why a 19ms discrepancy is significant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it's a standard on the system we're working on that delay must not be more than 10ms.