# timezone in php 5.6.x and above is not exactly?

Tags: centos, timezone

I'm using Linux CentOS 6.6 in my VPS Server

and installed php `5.6.12` and above (`php 7`)

also i did config php.ini `date.timezone=Europe/Amsterdam`

and use in `php` file something this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

but the time is not exactly it show me more than real time Amsterdam !!! also i checked for other timezone area but it was same problem !

for example if real time `Amsterdam` is `10:50:30` show me `10:58:27` !

you can see 8 min is more than real time !!!

I thought my problem was in version of `php`, so i updated it from `php5.6.12` to `php7.0.7` but it was not solved !

Comment: If the time is off by 7 minutes and 57 seconds, that has nothing to do with timezones. There's no timezone with an offset of +00:07:57. It simply means that your server's clock is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am convinced this has nothing to do with php. When you enter in the shell `date` - what do you get?

What about contacting the server provider regarding the time difference?

To me it looks like the NTP service is **not** running. Check Google for `NTP Service` or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786396/re-synchronize-linux-to-ntp-server).

If you have full `root` access to your server may be installing an NTP service would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem

I had a [Webmin](http://webmin.com) Control Panel on my Linux Server, so i checked `System Time` (in the left Menu: `Hardware-> System Time`) module and set `Timezone` to `UTC`, after i saw that system time was 8 min more than right time `UTC` !

I just set Minute and Second time according **`UTC`** world time at [worldtimeserver](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx)

thank you for attention

Comment: ok than you @AlBundy but i'm new user, where i most upvote you?